# Which plugin I should use for db migration for hibernate4?

Tags: database, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.3

I am using grails2.3.7 and hibernate4.
However, the default database-migration plugin is not working with hibernate4. 
Is there any other plugin that can do the same thing but support hibernate4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is updated to support hibernate4 now.

[database-migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what functionality you can do without, you may be able to use straight Liquibase in your project.  It is fairly simple to setup.  You could use the [manual](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html) or a [presentation I gave](https://bowerstudios.com/node/1056) to get yourself started.

You can always look at the source of the database-migration plugin to give you clues about how to set it up if you get stuck.